# Updating information for flagging a question

Tags: support, flags

I flagged a question on Stack Overflow, but now I want to update my comments for flagging that question. Is this possible?

Also is it possible to undo a flag on a question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can neither change nor delete your flag once you made it.

But don't worry too much about it. If a moderator does not agree with it and it gets *declined* then this is not the end of the world. Just move on.

Comment: first time i tried to flag a question, and i am not sure of all the options , Thanks for the info :)